# Convert XLS to CSV in Unix

Tags: unix, conversion, csv, xls

Is there an easy to compile plain C XLS (Excel sheet(s)) to CSV (or other text delimited format) converter for Linux or the BSDs that doesn't rely on Perl and installing a bunch of module perl modules or using X, any kind of GUI, or Windows?

I've looked at http://search.cpan.org/~ken/xls2csv/script/xls2csv and it's just about right except that I don't want to have to use CPAN on every machine I need this on to build test and install the requirements.

Answer (score 2):

No C but CPAN free ...

You can use [pyExcelerator](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyExcelerator) a python module to read/write excel files. As a bonus it comes with a nice converting tool: **py_xls2csv**. It is also **packaged** in debian (so probably in all debian-like and other distributions too) and freeBSD under the names [python-excelerator](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/python-excelerator) and [py-excelerator](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/ports/textproc/py-excelerator/) respectively.

Answer (score 2):

If you're happy with xls2csv as it runs in one machine, you can use [PAR::Packer](http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/PAR-Packer-0.991/lib/PAR/Packer.pm) to build a distributable package for all other machines with the same architecture. You can include as much of perl and its modules and dependencies as you want, to the point of creating a stand-alone executable with no perl dependencies whatsoever. Quoting from the forementioned perldoc:

```
   Stand-alone setup
           % pp -o packed.exe source.pl        # makes packed.exe
           # Now, deploy 'packed.exe' to target machine...
           $ packed.exe                        # run it
```