# On Unix, open xls file, and read the content, only the data

Tags: microsoft-excel, shell

Does any one know how to open xls file in shell on UNIX?

whether is there any tools to convert XLS to CSV?

Answer (score 1):

[Take a look here](https://superuser.com/questions/57530/convert-xls-to-csv-in-unix)

Can you convert to csv in windows first? That would help. Or just script it with python or perl.

Comment: thanks! that's very difficult to convert, because all the source file from server.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [python-excelerator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyexcelerator/) for this in the past.

```
apt-get install python-excelerator
```

Howto: http://ghantoos.org/2007/10/25/python-pyexcelerator-small-howto/

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea if this would work but I'm just throwing it out as a possible avenue to explore.  You can [install Windows Powershell on Linux](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/powershell-is-open-sourced-and-is-available-on-linux/).  With that, you might be able to parse Excel files.